# Passing a Closure as an Argument to another Function won't work

Tags: functional-programming, swift2, xcode7-beta6

I have a function `evaluate` that takes arguments. The first argument is an `Int`. The second argument of a closure that takes an `Int` and returns a `Double`. The function `evaluate` then returns a `[Double]`. The *k*’th element of the returned array is the result of evaluating the second argument with the value *k* for *k = 0, 1, ..., n*.

```
func evaluate(n: Int, myFunction: Int -> Double) -> [Double] {
    var doubles = [Double]()
    for i in 1...n {
        doubles[i] = myFunction(i)
    }

    return doubles
}

let polyTableClosure: Int -> Double = { return Double($0 * $0 * $0 + 2 * $0 + 4) }

print(evaluate(5, polyTableClosure))
```

Expecting something like: `[7, 16, 37, 76, 139]`

Comment: Thanks!!! @Filburt   Sorry for the troble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `myFunction:` label is missing. Your call of `evaluate` should be:

```
evaluate(5, myFunction: polyTableClosure)
```

Also, accessing an empty array at index `i` will not create a new slot at that index. It will fail.

You must append to the array:

```
for i in 1...n {
    doubles.append(myFunction(i))
}
```

Comment: yeah the problem is {doubles[i] = myFunction(i)}. I don't have to explicitly do it this way {evaluate(5, myFunction: polyTableClosure)}. This is {print(evaluate(5, polyTableClosure))} just working fine. Thanks a lot!!! I was pulling my hair for an hour on this.